# Why does the value of i become negative after some iterations

Tags: c

I have created the following program to find <s>factorial</s> factors, but I am not able to understand why the value of `i` becomes negative after a few iterations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,i;

    printf("enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("entered value is %d\n", a);

    for(i = 1; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("iterating for a = %d\n", a);
        b = a % i;
        if(b == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("a = %d, i = %d, modulo = %d\n", b);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your last `printf` is wrong, it should be `printf("a = %d , i = %d modulo = %d \n", a, i, b);`

Comment: just to be clear, there is the difference between **factorial** and **factorization**. Your program finds neither, but is closer to **factorization**.

Comment: By the way (can't edit my comment anymore), you shouldn't use variable names like `a, i, b`. Try using *meaningful* names.

Comment: @ComFreek: it is fine to add several comments — and you don't need to observe that you can't edit your comment any more.  While you can edit your comment, do (that's good practice, in general).  When you need to add another (time expired, no more space, different subject), add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix:

`printf("a = %d, i = %d, modulo = %d\n", b);`

to

`printf("a = %d, i = %d, modulo = %d\n", a, i, b);`

Also, your program doesn't find [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)!

```
b =1;
for(i = 1; i <= a; i++)    
    b*=i;
printf(" Factorial for a = %d \n", b);
```

Comment: sorry I meant to write factors.

Answer (score 2):

you do not print `i` in last `printf`. change it to:

```
printf("a = %d, i = %d, modulo = %d\n", a, i, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

No i not become 0. I try this code for 6 and 10 iteration. Its not giving negative value of i. In my case its giving value of i=1298 maybe garbage value. Maybe you are trying more in number of iteration thats why after some iterations negative value of i.